# set correct version of ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 16.04, apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

#### tl;dr

my system thinks it's supposed to download packages for bionic even though I am still on xenial. I can't upgrade from xenial to bionic, because I should first upgrade all available packages. When I try to do that, it downloads bionic packages and then aborts, since the OS version doesn't match the new package versions. **How do I tell my system it is still xenial and not bionic, yet?**

---

I began running the ubuntu upgrade program as explained on [this website](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver). So:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

then commenced running the upgrade program (after confirming I had installed `update-manager-core`) with

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and everything went as expected. Good so far. It asked me whether I wanted to proceed with "y" or "N" or see details with "d". For fun, I hit "d" and "enter". I look at details in the terminal. OK, that's all very interesting. Anyways. Upon reaching the end, it shows me

```
(END)
```

here's where I should have stopped and opened this here website instead of doing something stupid. I hit "enter", nothing happened, "escape" nothing happened, "backspace" nothing happened. Then I chose to hit "Ctrl+C" and the upgrade program aborted and I got taken back to the previous terminal content, but without prompt. I tried "y" to continue with the distro upgrade, but that failed. Alright, close the terminal, reopen it, do `sudo do-release-upgrade` again. Something went wrong, but I don't remember what at this point. In any case, I rebooted the whole system, opened the terminal and now we're here:

```
thymaro@ultra:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

thymaro@ultra:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease     
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:4 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease   
Hit:5 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

thymaro@ultra:~$ sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google
  .... {list of hundreds more packages}
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  checkbox-converged checkbox-gui curl gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 
  .... {list of dozens more packages}
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin autopoint binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu bolt 
  .... {list of hundreds more packages}
The following packages will be upgraded:
  a11y-profile-manager-indicator accountsservice acl acpid 
  .... {list of hundreds more packages}
2355 to upgrade, 615 to newly install, 77 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1'505 MB/2'207 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2'269 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libglvnd0 amd64 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3 [47.0 kB]
Get:2 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libwayland-egl1-mesa amd64 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3 [6'892 B]
Get:3 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libwayland-egl1 amd64 1.16.0-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.3 [5'464 B]
Get:4 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libqt5dbus5 amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 [195 kB]
... {about a thousand more lines downloading 'bionic' packages}
```

The question is at the beginning of the post under tl;dr.

Comment: What does the following command report? `lsb_release -a`
This could help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: Next time you view a file on the command line, showing line numbers at the bottom, and eventually `(END)`, press `Q` to exit the file viewer.

Comment: @dariofac it tells me I have xenial, Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Jos I should try to remember that. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do-release-upgrade` command changes your sources.

To change your sources back:

- Edit /etc/apt/sources.list (requires sudo).

  ```
  sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list          // CLI 
  //OR//
  sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list     // GUI
  ```
- Review each line carefully: Each line that says 'bionic' change back to 'xenial'.
- When complete and saved, run sudo apt update.